# Best practice for designing user schema in mongoDB when you have different types of users

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Stuck in planning user schema. Let me define the scenario
I have two types of users
-general users
-devs

General users: only have email and name field to store and they can only surf web
Devs: can have more fields related to their portfolio like github link, experience, domain etc.

I currently have two plans.
1st approach:
make two collections
-users {name,email,role}
-portfolios {userId,experience, domain..}
(Only devs role will be allowed to make post portfolio info)

2nd approach:
make only one collection and embed portfolio in that collection
-users
{
role,email,name,
portfolio: {domain,exp..}
}

But the only problem I'm facing in 2nd approach is to restrict "portfolio" field only update by those whose role is dev.

Need suggestion to model this type of scenario!
Using:
Node.js v14+
Mongoose 5.9+
MongoDB 4.4

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at discriminators, they're perfect for these things.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html

They behave independently but share the same collection. When you need to query all users you can use your User model, otherwise query either using generalUser discriminator or devUser discriminator. They can have their own methods and can even have their own unique indexes.